# How to redirect from service to the main controller in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

This is my first app using *Angularjs*.

I'm creating an app using **AngularJs** which brings tour details from API response. I have multiple controller, each controller has a different pages.

My problem is I have four links (links look like Spanish, France, India, America, etc.) on my each page footer. If I click on one of them, I should show respective API results on the main controller. Please look into the below diagram for understating pageflow.

[image: for reference]

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: what does your routes file look like?

Answer (score 0):

A service would be perfect for this. If you create a service with the function that shows the data, you can inject the service in each controller. That way if you click on the link in your footer, the data would show!

Check [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) for documentation and examples of angular services

Comment: So I need to pass the dependencies in each controller?

Comment: Yeah, if you create a service which you want to use in multiple controllers, you need to pass the dependency in each controller you want to use the service in.

Comment: Yes, you would need to pass the service's name into the controller application.controller('BlaBlaController', function ($scope, $yourservice) { });

Comment: If i want to redirect from my service to main controller with varibale?

Comment: Then give the function in your service a parameter!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have one page here :

Page1.php

You have called this page with **Page1Controller** .

and you want to use **MainController** in your `<form> ... </form>`, 
than use **ng-controller**...

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form ng-controller="MainController">
. . .  // Code here
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had an equivalent requirement before. This is how I did it.

Create your global method as a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) and use it to maintain the currently chosen API.

When the user clicks on the footer link, you can bind an *ng-click* event and *broadcast* an event that will be handled by the service's *$on* function.

You can check [this example](https://rclayton.silvrback.com/passing-state-via-services) for more info.

Comment: Thank you, If click on the button I'm calling the service. From service how to redirect main controller with response data?

Comment: You can broadcast events for that. In the service you can call $broadcast for the $rootScope and catch it in your main controller with $on. This will allow you to pass data and if you need in the future even reuse it in other controllers, services, directives etc.

Comment: I tried but nothing happened! I don't know where am I making mistake.

Comment: @Silambu Update your question with the source code you are using.

Comment: I had raised a another question with detail, please look into the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31051272/how-to-redirect-from-the-service-to-the-controller-with-the-response-data-in-ang